# Create own screen lock in android like hilocker

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-launcher

i am trying to create my own Screen lock application. activity designing part  i have done.

i create a one service that continuously running in background to check screen activity  is on front or not.  but when pressing home button, activity hide up to five second. service not able start it.

p`lease tell me how can i create my own screen lock application . any logic or source code or link to refer.`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the best example for you:

https://github.com/teddscofield/teddsdroidtools/wiki

**Please use stackoverflow-search:**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864300/create-a-lock-screen-of-my-own